# Dominant value in image-array

Tags: arrays

I'm trying to find the dominant color of an image which is represented by an array. The array contains RGB-values like (58, 112, 146) and (60, 114, 148).

Right now I'm using a divide and conquer algorithm to compute the dominant value in an array of ints, but I don't know how I can define the dominant value of an image-array.

Can I simply just count which full RGB value occurs the most (like seeing that (58, 112, 146) occurs 100 times, which is the most)?

Comment: Are you sure about the existence of more than one RGB vector? Or is it that each component (R, G and B) may differ among vectors?

Comment: What is your definition of dominant color ?  Convert RGB to HSL then create histogram array of hue() value or maybe of each HSL component ?  Maybe https://github.com/jquery/jquery-color can help to see implementation of conversion.  This is my crude understanding of how to do such things.  So dominant may mean you want to exact colour from hue() that has the highest number of pixel count in a histogram ?

Comment: You can count RGB values as-is but you might need 16Mb of memory to compute with 8bit counters, 32Mb with 16bit counters.  When you may find HSL gives you the output you want and only need ~1Kb of memory with 16bit counters.  This would gives the dominant hue.